# How to inspect outgoing HTTP requests of a single site on IIS with php installed?

Tags: php, iis, logging, url-rewriting

I have a IIS on windows server 2012 with a site that has Wordpress installed on it (URL Rewriter). How could I Log or Monitor all out going requests from php (server side)?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/advanced-logging-module/advanced-logging-for-iis-custom-logging ?

Answer (score 3):

Sending a request to another service or machine will be using any socket and no log will be enabled by default for this.In our applications, sending a request will normally be done using some library (e.g. in C#,it will be System.Net ,java it can be Apache Http Client,Php it can be HttpRequest etc) .

- One option is  you can resort to the logging capabilities of the
  library you are using.

  - for PHP HttpRequest,you can use the [ini settings](http://php.net/manual/fa/http.configuration.php) to do that
  - for .NET,you can enable using [system.net logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-configure-network-tracing)
- Another possible way is to route the requests through a proxy as most of the network libraries support a proxy.But this will have the implications of performance and all the issues created by proxy.

  - [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) is a good option
  - I am not sure why do you want to log all the requests outgoing,if for troubleshooting purpose,you [can use Fiddler as a reverse proxy](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/UseFiddlerAsReverseProxy)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I believe that there is a injected unwanted code with in the Wordpress theme, It is opensource but it is obfuscated. I want to know if the code is sending any data to another server.